# How do I automate creation of missing ServiceBus topics and queues in a .NET 7 WebJobs project?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

I'm migrating a WebJobs project from .NET 4.6 to .NET 7 and I came across a quite significant problem - my new project does not seem to create missing topics and queues in the ServiceBus namespace. I can't find a way to force it to do so either.

I found `AccessRights` argument in `ServiceBusTriggerAttribute` but that's not exposed by `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`.

I also tried tweaking configuration in `AddServiceBus(this IWebJobsBuilder builder, Action<ServiceBusOptions> configure)` but it doesn't seem to expose anything relevant to provisioning these topics/queues.

Am I missing something here or is there no way to automate it and I'll need to provision them myself?

P.S. I'm authenticating using a shared access key with "manage" permissions (just FYI)

#EDIT
I also found this issue raised against the WebJobs SDK. Unfortunately there's no explanation of any recommended approach in place of the `AccessRights` option - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer versions of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` package, there is no built-in capability to automatically create missing Service Bus topics and queues.  You need to provision them manually.

> To automate the creation of missing Service Bus topics and queues in a .NET 7 WebJobs project, you can leverage the Service Bus management libraries provided by Azure SDK.

And I couldn't find any information on how to force the creation of missing topics and queues in the ServiceBus namespace in .NET 7 WebJobs project.

Code reference taken from [Github code.](https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues.md)

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;

string connectionString = "ConnectionString";
string topic_Name = "mytopic11";
string queue_Name = "myqueue11";

var mgmtClnt = new ManagementClient(connectionString);
if (!await mgmtClnt.TopicExistsAsync(topic_Name))
{
    await mgmtClnt.CreateTopicAsync(new TopicDescription(topic_Name));
    Console.WriteLine($"Topic '{topic_Name}' created successfully.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Topic '{topic_Name}' already exists.");
}
if (!await mgmtClnt.QueueExistsAsync(queue_Name))
{
    await mgmtClnt.CreateQueueAsync(new QueueDescription(queue_Name));
    Console.WriteLine($"Queue '{queue_Name}' created successfully.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Queue '{queue_Name}' already exists.");
}
await mgmtClnt.CloseAsync();
```

`.CSProj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

- Created Service Bus topic or queue in azure.
  [image]
- If the Service bus topic or queue already exists

[image]

For further information, refer to the [MSDoc1.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk)

Comment: I see, I had hoped that perhaps there's a replacement for the built-in management that does not require maintaining the implementation. Well, thank you!